# How to solve Error 2 in Make command on Windows?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make, gdal

I'm trying to install the following GitHub Repository in my machine:
[Br-Altlas](https://github.com/carolinabigonha/br-atlas)
The instructions tell me to install Gdal before clonning it, and then run npm install and run the command "make".
When I run the make command in the Git Bash, I have the following response:

```
mkdir -p geo/
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON geo/ac-municipalities.json tmp/ac-municipalities/map.shp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON geo/ac-municipalities.json tmp/ac-municipalities/map.shp, ...) failed.
make (e=2):The system cannot find the specified file.
make: *** [Makefile:70: geo/ac-municipalities.json] Error 2
```

And when I run the same command in the Windows Power Shell, my answer is this:

```
mkdir -p zip/
Command syntax is incorrect.
make: *** [Makefile:48: zip/ac-municipalities.zip] Error 1
```

I found some simmilar issues, but couldn't find a solution that solves it for me.

The content of the MakerFile is this:

```
# -- Configurations

# TopoJSON configurations
TOPOJSON = node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/.bin/topojson -q 1e6

# All Brazilian states
STATES = \
    ac al am ap ba ce df es go ma \
    mg ms mt pa pb pe pi pr rj rn \
    ro rr rs sc se sp to

all: \
    node_modules \
    $(addprefix topo/,$(addsuffix -municipalities.json,$(STATES))) \
    $(addprefix topo/,$(addsuffix -micro.json,$(STATES))) \
    $(addprefix topo/,$(addsuffix -meso.json,$(STATES))) \
    $(addprefix topo/,$(addsuffix -state.json,$(STATES))) \
    permission

# Install dependencies
node_modules:
    npm install

# Add execute permission
permission:
    chmod +x scripts/merge.py

# .SECONDARY with no dependencies marks all file targets mentioned in the makefile as secondary.
.SECONDARY:

# -- Downloading and extracting IBGE files

# Downloads the zip files
# ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/municipio_2010/
zip/%.zip:
    $(eval STATE := $(patsubst %-municipalities,%,$*))
    $(eval STATE := $(patsubst %-micro,%,$(STATE)))
    $(eval STATE := $(patsubst %-meso,%,$(STATE)))
    $(eval STATE := $(patsubst %-state,%,$(STATE)))
    $(eval FILENAME := $(subst -municipalities,_municipios,$*))
    $(eval FILENAME := $(subst -micro,_microrregioes,$(FILENAME)))
    $(eval FILENAME := $(subst -meso,_mesorregioes,$(FILENAME)))
    $(eval FILENAME := $(subst -state,_unidades_da_federacao,$(FILENAME)))
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    curl 'ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2010/$(STATE)/$(FILENAME).zip' -o $@.download
    mv $@.download $@

# Extracts the files
tmp/%/: zip/%.zip
    rm -rf $(basename $@)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    unzip -d tmp/$* $<
    $(eval REGION := $(patsubst %-municipalities,municipalities,$*))
    $(eval REGION := $(patsubst %-micro,micro,$*))
    $(eval REGION := $(patsubst %-meso,meso,$*))
    $(eval REGION := $(patsubst %-state,state,$*))
    mv $@/*.shp $@/map.shp
    mv $@/*.shx $@/map.shx
    mv $@/*.dbf $@/map.dbf
    mv $@/*.prj $@/map.prj

# -- Generate GeoJSON files

geo/%.json: tmp/%/
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON $@ tmp/$*/map.shp
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 $@ > $@.utf8
    mv $@.utf8 $@
    touch $@

# -- Generating TopoJSON files for each state

# For individual states, municipality level
topo/%-municipalities.json: geo/%-municipalities.json
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=CD_GEOCODM -p name=NM_MUNICIP -o $@ municipalities=$^
    touch $@

# For individual states, micro-region level
topo/%-micro.json: geo/%-micro.json
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=NM_MICRO -p name=NM_MICRO -o $@ micro=$^
    touch $@

# For individual states, meso-region level
topo/%-meso.json: geo/%-meso.json
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=NM_MESO -p name=NM_MESO -o $@ meso=$^
    touch $@

# For individual states, state level:
topo/%-state.json: geo/%-state.json
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=CD_GEOCODU -p name=NM_ESTADO -p region=NM_REGIAO -o $@ state=$^
    touch $@

# -- Generating TopoJSON files for Brazil

# For Brazil with municipalities
topo/br-municipalities.json: $(addprefix geo/,$(addsuffix -municipalities.json,$(STATES)))
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=CD_GEOCODM -p name=NM_MUNICIP -o $@ -- $^
    ./scripts/merge.py $@ > $@.merged
    mv $@.merged $@

# For Brasil with states
topo/br-states.json: $(addprefix geo/,$(addsuffix -state.json,$(STATES)))
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TOPOJSON) --id-property=CD_GEOCODU -p name=NM_ESTADO -p region=NM_REGIAO -o $@ -- $^
    ./scripts/merge.py $@ > $@.merged
    mv $@.merged $@

# Simplified version of state file
topo/br-states.min.json: topo/br-states.json
    $(TOPOJSON) -p --simplify-proportion=.2 -o $@ -- $^

# -- Clean

# Clean temporary files
clean-tmp:
    rm -rf tmp

# Clean extra files
clean-extra:
    rm -rf zip
    rm -rf tmp

# Clean result files
clean-result:
    rm -rf shp
    rm -rf geo
    rm -rf topo

# Clean everything
clean: clean-tmp clean-result clean-extra
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: The error message isn't complaining about `mkdir`.  it's complaining that it can't find `ogr2ogr`: _CreateProcess(NULL, ogr2ogr ..._

Comment: I just pasted the whole error message. So the error it's in the MakerFile?

Comment: No.  The error is that you don't have the program `ogr2ogr` installed on your system, or if you do you don't have it in your PATH so make can't find it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try to solve it